# What is the difference in meaning between these sentences?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences:

> 1. Shall I get her to wait outside?
> 2. Shall I get her waiting outside?

I am not sure of using "get" correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the form used here is "get (someone) to do (something)". An action is needed in the predicate.

> 1. Shall I **get** her(someone) to wait outside(to do something)?

However "waiting" is a state, not an action. So you cannot use it as written in example 2. However using a verb that describes state, like *to be*, you could say:

> How long will you **be** waiting outside?

Comment: I got Joe, now you gotta get Jane. Ok, but she runs outside every time I get near her.  She waits out there until she thinks I'm gone-  Hmm, Shall I get her waiting outside?  Is that legal?

Comment: @Jim Nope. "Shall I get her *while she is* waiting outside?"